# Char literal regex in Flex

Tags: regex, compiler-construction, flex-lexer

I am coding a C compiler in C++, Flex&bison. Right now I am working on scanning literals in Flex. I cannot for my life figure out how to write a regex that would match a char literal (`'x'`). This is my code right now -

```
%option noyywrap
%{
    #include "parser.hpp"

    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    
    #define SAVE_TOKEN yylval.str = new std::string(yytext, yyleng)
    #define TOKEN(t) (yylval.token = t)
%}

DATATYPE int|double|long|char|float
IDENTIFIER [_a-zA-Z]{1}[_a-zA-Z0-9]*
INTEGER [0-9]+
FLOAT [0-9].[0-9]
CHAR '([^'\\\n]|\\.)'
EMPTY_CHAR ''
EQUAL "="
SEMICOLON ";"
SPACE [ ]
TAB [\t]
NEWLINE [\n]

%%
{DATATYPE} SAVE_TOKEN; return TYPE;
{INTEGER} SAVE_TOKEN; return INT;
{FLOAT} SAVE_TOKEN; return FLOAT;
{CHAR} SAVE_TOKEN; return CHAR;
{IDENTIFIER} SAVE_TOKEN; return ID;
{SEMICOLON} return TOKEN(SEMICOLON);
{EQUAL} return TOKEN(EQUAL);
{SPACE} ;
{TAB} ;
{NEWLINE} ;
%%
```

Does anyone know how to make `CHAR` match char literals?
here's my bison code -

```
%code requires {
    #include "AssignmentAST.h"
    #include "TypeAST.h"
    #include "IntAST.h"
    #include "FloatAST.h"
    #include "ScalarDeclAST.h"
    #include "ProgramAST.h"
    #include "StmtAST.h"
    #include "StmtListAST.h"
    #include "IdentifierAST.h"
    #include "DeclAST.h"
    #include <cstdio>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
}

%{
    #include <cstdio>
    extern int yylex();
    void yyerror(const char* s) {printf("ERROR %s\n", s);}
    
%}

%code{
    ProgramAST *program;
}
 
%union {
    ProgramAST* program;
    DeclAST* decl;
    TypeAST* type;
    ExprAST* expr;
    StmtAST* stmt;
    IdentifierAST* ident;
    ScalarDeclAST* sc_decl;
    std::string *str;
    int token;
}

%token <str> ID TYPE INT FLOAT CHAR
%token <token> SEMICOLON EQUAL

%type <program> program
%type <decl> decl
%type <sc_decl> sc_decl
%type <type> type
%type <expr> expr
%type <stmt> stmt;
%type <ident> ident;


%start program

%%
program : stmts { printf("program"); }
        ;

stmts : stmt SEMICOLON { printf("stmt1"); }
      | stmt SEMICOLON stmts { printf("stmts"); }
      ;   

stmt : decl { $$ = $1; printf("stmt"); }
     | expr { printf("expr"); }
     ;

decl : sc_decl { $$ = $1; }
     ;

sc_decl : type ident { $$ = new ScalarDeclAST($<type>1, $<ident>2); }
        ;

type : TYPE { $$ = new TypeAST(*$1); delete $1; }
     ;

expr : INT { $$ = new IntAST(atol($1->c_str())); delete $1; }
     | FLOAT{ $$ = new FloatAST(atof($1->c_str())); delete $1; }
     | CHAR { puts($1->c_str()); delete $1; }
     ;

ident : ID { $$ = new IdentifierAST(*$1); delete $1; }
      ;
%%
```

I cannot add all of my C++ files.
When I tried running this, and inputting the line `int x;`, it recognised `x` as a char rather than an identifier.

Here's my `main.cpp`

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

extern int yyparse();
extern int parser_main();
extern FILE* yyin;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    try
    {
        FILE* as = nullptr;
        if (argc == 2)
        {
            fopen_s(&as, argv[1], "r");
            if (as != nullptr)
                yyin = as;
        }

        yyparse();
        
        if (as != nullptr)
        {
            fclose(as);
        }

    }
    catch (...)
    {
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In what way does your current pattern not work as you want? It looks fine to me.

Comment: it doesn't require the two apostrophes, so my one char identifiers are getting caught there too

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE] showing a character that's not surrounded by quotes being accepted by your pattern? When I change your code the minimal amount to make it self-contained and try it on an input like `x`, it produces an identifier token as expected.

Comment: You don't implement a fall-back pattern, so any input which doesn't match one of your patterns will automatically trigger (f)lex's default fallback action, which is `ECHO`.  That can be confusing. You should include an explicit default action, which might do something like return an invalid token, or print an error to stderr, or both. I also highly recommend `%option nodefault`, which will cause Bison to warn you if there is some input which doesn't match any pattern.

Comment: @sepp2k when I do something like `int x;` it returns `x` as a char rather than an identifier.

Comment: @rici I've got a bison file too. I don't think my problem is what you are saying, as when I run it in debug mode using visual studio I can see that and identifier, `x` for example, triggers the wrong regex

Comment: @alonkh2: Make sure that you compiled your lexer with the correct version of the bison-generated header. Then enable bison tracing (see "debugging your parser" in the bison manual) and see what tokens you are receiving. You can also give flex the `-d` flag to generate a lexer which reports which pattern matches (by line number in your `.l` file.)

Comment: If you don't provide enough information, you force us to guess what you are actually doing. That's not good for you or for me. That's why we always ask for a [mre]. You were already asked for one, so now it's twice.

Comment: @rici I would provide you with such example, only my project includes about 25 C++ files, and I can not copy the contents of them all.

Comment: I've add all I can.

Comment: Please review the guidance for providing a [mre] again. You have posted a lot of unrelated code which only distracts from the actual problem and makes it less likely that someone will step up and attempt to do the debugging work we expect you to already have performed. Demonstrating the problem with a few dozen lines of code is also more likely to help you solve the problem yourself, perhaps through improving your understanding of the mechanism which isn't working like you expect.